# How publish an "YUV422 packed" image, aravis + basler

Tags: ros, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using aravis driver+ basler camera + Camara_aravis node.
My camera can only give images with format:
-ARV_PIXEL_FORMAT_YUV_422_PACKED
-ARV_PIXEL_FORMAT_YUV_422_YUYV_PACKED
-ARV_PIXEL_FORMAT_BAYER_BG_8
-ARV_PIXEL_FORMAT_BAYER_BG_12

I have changed Camara_aravis node

msg.encoding = sensor_msgs::image_encodings::YUV422 ;
msg.step =  g_width*2;

But when I subscribe the image:
rosrun image_view  image_view image:=/cam1/image_raw theora

I get an image with wrong colors  (blue is yellow, blue is orange...).

I think that the problems comes from ARV_PIXEL_FORMAT_YUV_422_PACKED format which is different of sensor_msgs::image_encodings::YUV422.

How can I fix this?

If I use ARV_PIXEL_FORMAT_BAYER_BG_8 with sensor_msgs::image_encodings::BAYER_BGGR8. I get a crash:

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv_bridge::Exception'
what():  Unsupported conversion from [bayer_bggr8] to [rgb8]
Aborted (core dumped)

What is the best way to publish images of this format?

My regards,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59763/how-publish-an-%22yuv422-packed%22-image,-aravis-+-basler/) by [Filipe Santos](https://answers.ros.org/users/907/filipe-santos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 346 on 2013-04-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok... My faults. It is solved.

I should use http://www.ros.org/wiki/image_proc
and also run
rosrun image_view image_view image:=/cam1/image_raw theora (without theora)

regards

---

Originally posted by [Filipe Santos](https://answers.ros.org/users/907/filipe-santos/) with karma: 346 on 2013-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0